# Search/Filter nested Array Javascript/Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter, nested

For my React.js project I would like to create a search-filter of a nested Array. Users will search with an input-field.

```
    var dataExample = [
  {
    type: "human", details: [
    {id: 1, name: "Peter", description: "friendly, black-hair"},
    {id: 5, name: "Susan", description: "blond"}
      ]
  },

  {
    type: "animal", details: [
    {id: 2, name: "Will", description: "lazy, cute"},
    {id: 3, name: "Bonny", description: "beautiful"}
      ]
  }
];
```

In my search-input-field I want to look for "name" **or** something in "description". **The data structure of the array should remain the same.**

The output when I'm searching for "friendly" **or** "Peter" should be:

```
[
  {
    type: "human", details: [
    {id: 1, name: "Peter", description: "friendly, black-hair"}
      ]
  }
];
```

Now I tried something like this:

```
  let myfilter = dataExample.filter((data) => {
  data.details.filter((items) => {
    return (items.type.indexOf("human") !== -1 ||       //input of user
              items.description.indexOf("friendly"))
  })
})
```

Unfortunately, this is not how it works. Can anybody help me? Lodash would be no problem, too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `array#filter` and to check for your word you can use `string#incldues`.

```js
const dataExample = [ { type: "human", details: [ {id: 1, name: "Peter", description: "friendly, black-hair"}, {id: 5, name: "Susan", description: "blond"} ] }, { type: "animal",details: [ {id: 2, name: "Will", description: "lazy, cute"}, {id: 3, name: "Bonny", description: "beautiful"} ] } ],
  term = 'Peter',
  result = dataExample.reduce((r, {type,details}) => {
      let o = details.filter(({name,description}) => name.includes(term) || description.includes(term));
      if(o && o.length)
        r.push({type, details : [...o]});
      return r;
  },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything works perfect! Learned something new again.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your code after all. If the search is empty (term = ' '), an array at "Details" with only length 1 is displayed. It should be an array with 2 objects. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: What should be the output when term is empty?

Comment: The output of an empty String in "includes" should be the same array as dataExample. With your code the output are the two objects ("human" and "animal") and only one object in the "details"-array (instead of two objects).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples without lodash.

```
  var dataAll = [
        {
            type: "human",
            details: [
                {id: 1, name: "Peter", description: "friendly, black-hair"},
                {id: 5, name: "Susan", description: "blond"}
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "animal",
            details: [
                {id: 2, name: "Will", description: "lazy, cute"},
                {id: 3, name: "Bonny", description: "beautiful"}
            ]
        }
    ];

    var entryTypeFilter = data => data.type.indexOf("hum") !== -1;
    var entryDetailDescFilter = data => data.description.indexOf("friend") !== -1;
    var entryDetailsMapper = data => {
        return {
            type: data.type,
            details: data.details.filter(entryDetailDescFilter)
        };
    };
    var entryNoDetailsFilter = data => data.details && data.details.length !== 0;

    var dataFilteredByType = dataAll.filter(entryTypeFilter);
    var dataFilteredByDesc = dataAll.map(entryDetailsMapper);
    var dataFilteredByTypeAndDesc = dataAll.filter(entryTypeFilter).map(entryDetailsMapper);
    var dataFilteredByDescTrimmingEmptyDetailEntries = dataAll.map(entryDetailsMapper).filter(entryNoDetailsFilter);
```

- In modern javascript you might want to search on how to use the `...` keyword for the mapping callback functions.